# How to import data form one spreadsheet into another Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am trying to connect 2 Google sheets (a Check-in and a Check-out Google sheet) to feed data off a management sheet. I don't know what formula or function to use to connect the 2 sheets to feed off the management sheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IMPORTRANGE`:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL of spreadsheet", "Sheet name!A1:D")
```

**note:** it will first prompt you to allow access